# Powershell - get the output from this Get-WmiObject command (getting the number of cores using powershell)

Tags: powershell

So my aim is to get the number of cores on the machine my powershell script runs on and work with it as an integer. Some googleing lead me to this nice and simple command to get the number of cores:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem | fl NumberOfLogicalProcessors
```

Which displays an output like this:

NumberOfLogicalProcessors : 4

Now my issue is, how so I extract the number "4" from this? I tried .Split(":") but the output is not a string so that doesn't work. Next I tried

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem | fl NumberOfLogicalProcessors | select NumberOfLogicalProcessors
```

But this just yields:

"NumberOfLogicalProcessors
--------------------------------------"

Not helpful. What am I missing? What is this Get-WmiObject returning and how do I work with it?

Edit: 
Thank you mhu, that did the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `Format-List` (fl), but directly select the required property, like this:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem | select "NumberOfLogicalProcessors" -ExpandProperty "NumberOfLogicalProcessors"
```

As said by Mike, you could shorten this to:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem | select -ExpandProperty "NumberOfLogicalProcessors"
```

Comment: I would omit the first "NumberOfLogicalProcessors" after the select.